# Sample Admin Page

Tags: visualforce

how to design a sample admin page. **(like our sales force admin page)**

Suppose when i click the My Personal Information below it shows Personal Information so on...

Any body please provide the logic for that functionality.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. This question got closed by the community for being far too broad. THe best thing to do is do some research, get started, and then post when you get stuck with something specific. The Developer Boards are also a great place to get more general help. As a quick tip though, you can't add any pages to the Salesforce.com setup screens.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start with is to give a glance on [Visualforce Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm). Following that is the [Visualforce Cookbook](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/category/visualforce/recent) which will give you kick start on practical things.

As you want to design sample admin page,

> 1. Create a visualforce page with any of the standard controller. For example, Account
> 2. Creating the above would give you look and feel same like salesforce UI.
> 3. Additionally, you can create an extension to add more functionality or interfaces to the visualforce pages.

If you really want to create salesforce admin page from the scratch, then it involves a lot of effort and coding time which you can attempt after getting some hands-on with the fundamentals.